# Using string filenames in windows

Tags: python, windows, wkhtmltopdf

I have this lines working fine on linux:

```
input_file = '%s/my_input.html' % settings.FILE_PATH
args =['wkhtmltopdf', input_file, '-']
popen = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

`wkhtmltopdf` in Windows can't while on linux I have no problems at all. I think this is slash/backslash related problem, but have no idea how to solve it. Already tried using backslash and double backslashes.

Any suggestions?

Same error in all these variations:

```
"C:\\tmp\\input.html"

"C:\tmp\input.html"

os.path.join("C:\\tmp", "input.html")

'%s%sinput.html' % ('C:\\tmp', os.path.sep)
```

> WindowsError at /admin/salidas/pdf/ [Error 2] El sistema no puede
>   hallar el archivo especificado

That means The system can't find the specified file.

That on the Popen Line

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: I think the message means "The system can't find the specified file"

Comment: I would use raw strings where ever you specify strings, and are you *sure* the file exists where you are trying to open it? Can you see it inside the python shell when you do a `import os` followed by `os.listdir(your_directory_path_here)`. Does the file show up in the list returned?

Comment: Where does `t /admin/salidas/pdf/ ` come from this must be a path in your code?

Comment: Mark... that is the current URL I am executing (It is a django project)

Comment: But where do you call or open it in your code - not the code you are showing

Answer (score 2):

Don't treat file paths as simple strings but use the python library classes to manipilate them as paths. In this case [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)

```
input_file = os.path.join( settings.FILE_PATH, my_input.html)
```

Answer (score 1):

In general try using raw strings when dealing with paths .. i.e., pre-pend an `r` before your path name. E.g.,

```
my_path = 'c:\test\bob`
```

better as

```
my_path = r'c:\test\bob`
```

as it will prevent the `\t` and `\b` in the path specification of being interpreted against your interest.

Also, take a look at the [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module with its OS specific functions/information re which path separators ([os.sep](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.sep#os.sep)) used on the given OS, and [join()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=join#os.path.join)  functions etc - that would be preferable to using strings directly to specify/manipulate paths.

Answer (score 0):

use `os.path.sep`, it returns **OS** dependent path separator (`\\` on windows and `/` on linux)

```
>>> import os
>>> FILE_PATH='somepath'
>>> input_file='%s%smy_input.html' % (FILE_PATH,os.path.sep)
>>> input_file
'somepath\\my_input.html'   #on windows on linux it returns 'somepath/my_input.html'
```

Comment: @juanefren check this out : <http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#converting-argument-sequence>